# Firebase Storage add firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com problem

Tags: firebase-storage

I'm having some problems with Firebase storage lately.

We have this error message i the browser when we try to access a file that we just uploaded

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Could not get object. Please ensure firebase- 
         storage@system.gserviceaccount.com is set as an OWNER of this 
         object."
     }
}
```

We tried to add the permission for the bucket in the console but it doesn't work. Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please instead of images copy your source code with the proper formatting. See the documentation on [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22364732)

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Does `firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com` have `Storage Admin` role?

You can check it in GCP by going to `Storage > Browser` and selecting `Edit Bucket Permissions` from the kebab menu (⋮) next to the bucket name.

Are you on a paid plan (Blaze)? This might actually be a problem with your Billing Account (like an expired credit card) that you missed. In this case, you would be getting this error trying to access objects in all but the default bucket. Fixing Billing Account problem should fix the access problem.